# Access value into result bootstrap modal with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/modal.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.users = data.data;

        $scope.users.forEach(function(e) {
            e._is_ok = false;
        });

        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close(true);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };
    }],
    size: 'md',
    }).result.then(function(res) {

    if (res === true) {
        console.log("Access User", $scope.users);
    }
});
```

Trying to access scope for users into result that says undefined $scope.users Why and how can i fix it please guide thanks in advance.

Comment: your `$http` request should be inside modal's controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/modal.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

      $scope.users = data.data;
      $scope.users.forEach(function(e){
          e._is_ok = false;
      });


      $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.users);
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
      };
    }],
    size: 'md',
  }).result.then(function (users) {

    if (users) {
      console.log("Access User", users);

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$scope.users` defined inside the model controller. You are accessing it from outside the model controller. You can either create a service to get and set values between 2 controllers or you can make the scope variable rootScope.

```
$modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/modals/modal.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance','$rootScope' function ($scope, $modalInstance, $rootScope) {

          $rootScope.users = data.data;
          $rootScope.users.forEach(function(e){
              e._is_ok = false;
          });


          $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close(true);
          };

          $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
          };
        }],
        size: 'md',
      }).result.then(function (res) {

        if (res === true) {
          console.log("Access User", $rootScope.users);

        }
});
```

Comment: Using $rootScope that way is against best practices. It's like writing new properties on `window` global object, you must avoid it.

Comment: Agreed. best way i think is to create a factory and provide get set method to call from the controllers